# How to set CURL options when using Kohana Request

Tags: php, curl, kohana, kohana-3.2

Trying to use the Request class to get an external resources, but can't figure out how to set more default curl options.

I get the data like this:

```
$data = Request::factory($url)->execute()->body();
```

I figured adding CURL options was a simple matter of making a copy of `system/config/curl.php` into my application config folder and then setting the options there (I assume they will be merged?).

But those options don't seem to be used at all? Tried to do a `var_dump` in `Kohana_Request_Client_Curl` after all the options should've been set, but I can only find the ones set directly there in that method, which makes sense as I can't seem to find anywhere these options are actually fetched from the config file...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is more detailed example:

```
$request = Request::factory($some_url);

$request->client()->options(array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
));
```

Answer (score 2):

The Request_Curl class doesn't look at that config file. You'll have to use `->options()` manually to set the curl params.

Comment: On what? The Request object doesn't seem to have any options method.

Comment: I think it should be something like: $request->get_client()->options($options);

Comment: `$request->client()->options($options)`