# Problems with SSL connections in Kohana

Tags: php, ssl, twitter, oauth, kohana

Realize authorization tweeted via OAuth module Frameworks Kohana. At the first request to the server crash bug twitter SSL certificate:

> Kohana_OAuth_Exception [ 0 ]: Error fetching remote https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token [ status 0 ] SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

How can I resolve this issue without getting into the code module? PS server is currently under windows

> Apache-2.4.4
>
> PHP 5.4.13

Comment: You might try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478283/paypal-access-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: You can see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774976/how-to-set-curl-options-when-using-kohana-request